# Changing the Pandas DataFrame structure in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe in Python that looks like below:

```
BatchID | EventTime

Test1   | 2020-03-10 10:22:21

Test1   | 2020-03-10 10:22:27

Test1   | 2020-03-10 10:22:31

Test2   | 2020-03-10 10:36:00

Test2   | 2020-03-10 10:36:02

Test2   | 2020-03-10 10:36:04
```

I want to restructure it such that it looks like as shown below:

```
BatchID --> Batch Start --> Batch End

Test1  --> 2020-03-10 10:22:21 --> 2020-03-10 10:22:31
Test2  --> 2020-03-10 10:36:00 --> 2020-03-10 10:36:04
```

Where for every unique Batch ID, I want to pick the start time and end time and frame it into one row.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with `agg` and `min, max`:

```
df.groupby('BatchID')['EventTime'].agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index()
```

```
  BatchID                 min                 max
0   Test1 2020-03-10 10:22:21 2020-03-10 10:22:31
1   Test2 2020-03-10 10:36:00 2020-03-10 10:36:04
```